# Error in Computing the Coherence Score – AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id2token'

Tags: python, scipy, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I am a beginner in NLP and it's my first time to do Topic Modeling. I was able to generate my model however I cannot produce the coherence metric.

Converting the term-document matrix into a new gensim format, from df --> sparse matrix --> gensim corpus

```
sparse_counts = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(data_dtm)
corpus = matutils.Sparse2Corpus(sparse_counts)
corpus
```

[image]

```
df_lemmatized.head()
```

[image]

```
# Gensim also requires dictionary of the all terms and their respective location in the term-document matrix
tfidfv = pickle.load(open("tfidf.pkl", "rb"))
id2word = dict((v, k) for k, v in tfidfv.vocabulary_.items())
id2word
```

[image]

This is my model:

```
lda = models.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, num_topics=15, passes=10, random_state=43)
lda.print_topics()
```

[image]

And finally, here is where I attempted to get Coherence Score Using Coherence Model:

```
# Compute Perplexity
print('\nPerplexity: ', lda.log_perplexity(corpus))  

# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda, texts=df_lemmatized.long_title, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
print('\nCoherence Score: ', coherence_lda)
```

This is the error:

*---> 57     if not dictionary.id2token:  # may not be initialized in the standard gensim.corpora.Dictionary
     58         setattr(dictionary, 'id2token', {v: k for k, v in dictionary.token2id.items()})
     59 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'id2token'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I can't reproduce the error. So, I will take a guess! The problem is within your `id2word`, it should be a `corpora.dictionary.Dictionary` not just `dict`. So, you need to do the following:

```
>>> from gensim import corpora
>>>
>>> word2id = dict((k, v) for k, v in tfidfv.vocabulary_.items())
>>> d = corpora.Dictionary()
>>> d.id2token = id2word
>>> d.token2id = word2id
>>> #...
>>> # change `id2word` to `d`
>>> coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda, texts=df_lemmatized.long_title, dictionary=d, coherence='c_v')
```

And I think it should work just fine now!

Comment: Thank you for responding... Unfortunately it throwing a "KeyError:" message

Comment: Did you resolve the KeyError? Have the same issue

Comment: @Grumpybeard This answer wasn't about a `KeyError`. Anyway, what's the error that you got?